# Timer.tick within 1 min back-forth

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have 2 Form and i want it to be slide show back & forth within 1 minute.

Please write down the code thank you!

My Code:

Form 1

```
Private Sub BunifuCheckbox1_OnChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuCheckbox1.OnChange
    If BunifuCheckbox1.Checked Then
        tmrSLIDE.Enabled = True
        tmrSLIDE.Start()
    Else
        tmrSLIDE.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub tmrSLIDE_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrSLIDE.Tick
    trs1.ShowSync(Form2)
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Form 2:

```
Private Sub BunifuCheckbox1_OnChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuCheckbox1.OnChange
    If BunifuCheckbox1.Checked Then
        tmrSLIDE2.Enabled = True
        tmrSLIDE2.Start()
    Else
        tmrSLIDE2.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub tmrSLIDE_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrSLIDE2.Tick
    trs2.ShowSync(Form1)
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Property tmrSLIDE interval = 60000
property tmrSLIDE2 interval = 120000
```

I just Want to have 1 Checkbox with a simplified code thank you!

Comment: You will need to include the code you have tried and the reason it didn't work out. You need to take the [tour]

Comment: Oh yea sure, i forget that... Thx for the advice

Comment: I recommend adding the bunifu tag, because it looks like you're using [this](https://docs.bunifuframework.com/en/articles/2273086-bunifu-transition); also the visual-studio-2019 tag is probably not necessary.

Comment: i've added that but i want that to be on the timer

Comment: Check the preview in the question editor. If is doesn't look correct then fix it before you post. Selecting your code that you have copied and pasted from Visual Studio then clicking the { } icon from the toolbar in the editor will properly format your code.

Comment: sorry i'm new here... but it's suggested by someone & fix for the formated code thanks...
how about the timer?

Comment: What is `trs2`? I am not familiar with `.ShowSnyc`. Is this a third party control method?

Comment: trs2 is a transition2 on the Form 2 i'm using bunifu transition